# NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I got simple_form with multiple checkboxes, that save an array with names of some methods in my model. form looks like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @testrun do |f| %>

<%= f.input :testcase, as: :check_boxes,
      collection: [["test1", :test1], ["test2", :test2]] %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

my create method in controller looks like:

```
def create
    @testrun = Testrun.new(testrun_params)

    if @testrun.save
      Testrun.delay.process!(@testrun.id)
      redirect_to @testrun, notice: 'Test run was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

In my model i have method `process!` which i need to run methods in an array.

```
  def process!
    .
    .
    .
    @test = Case.new(self)
    @testrun[:testcase].each do |testcase|
      @test.send testcase
    end
  end
```

when i start process, i got error `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Where i was wrong?

Comment: you are passing just ID to process! Testrun.delay.process!(@testrun.id)

Comment: Where are you getting the `@testrun` instance variable from in your model? Or even more important where do you think you´re getting it from? Instance variables are not globals. You cannot access your controllers instance variables from the model. You have to pass them to the model.

Comment: And there is something wrong with the code as presented here as this should give a `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments` error before it ever reaches that line. Ruby enforces the number of arguments passed to methods. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve